# Customizing the mobile for Blind in android

Tags: android

i have developed some applications for blind which makes them to use basic mobile functionalities like making call, add contact,delete contact. but now i am in dilemma that how the blind  can even unlock the mobile if he is given the android mobile and navigate through the menu to reach the specific application. So does one need to customize the entire OS by making it interactive to the blind user by responding to "Voice commands" (like "unlock mobile" should unlock it) to enable him to use mobile functionalites.

But i have tried some of the voice recognition tutorials,Voice recogntition approach was not accurate. What could be the possible way to customize the mobile for blind and is it possible to access the internals of the OS and customize it, to make it respond to voice commands?
how to code it i am not getting.

please throw some light on this problem. in what way it could be made possible.

Comment: S you want an approach like [this](http://www.codefactory.es/en/products.asp?id=415#getit) one?

Comment: There is this new feature "explore by touch". www.youtube.com/watch?v=Boz3yVBz1hM

Comment: @iturki: yes i have seen that application, but how to make it possible. and when u install that app on my mobile how the blind can reach it and use it. how to integrate developed applications into single app( like Access Demo) and make it read its name when user touches on each and every application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android comes with accessibility services which can be used. It has a talk back service which could be used to enabled voice response on touch.

Refer to the link below for more details

http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/android_access/index.html

http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/android_access/services.html

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but can i make the customization possible on my own.how can i intergrate the developed apps into single app like Mobile Accessibility Demo and use them with touch input and voice mode response. and i think unlocking mobile and reaching the app is not possible...